# Sending preflight (OPTIONS) AJAX request with crendentianals

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a client-side application that use server-side API. The client-side and the server-side application placed on different domains. A session id placed in cookies on the server side. So, the client-side application should send cookies in every AJAX request. I use `withCredentials` option in Xhr object to send headers with every AJAX request. The problem is that there is no headers in preflight OPTIONS request. But I need this cookies because the server side should khow who sends this request, because every user has his own routes.

Comment: post your code please..... no one can help seeing just words

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the browser will never send credentials on an `OPTIONS` request. Those requests exist to allow the browser to retrieve `Access-Control-*` response headers.
Take a look at the [CORS Article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials), discussing the use of `withCredentials` on the `XMLHttpRequest` and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` in the response. Browsers will **reject** any response that does not contain the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` header, and **not** make the response available to the invoking web content.

Also, consider using Token-Auth instead of Cookies. [Good read here](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/)